# How should intermediate library dependencies be handled in c++?

Tags: c++, git, docker

I'm building a c++ repo that depends on external company repos that exist to support this repo. I have to build these to target certain versions of boost and other libraries specific to my system. At the end of the (long) build process, I have several static libraries and my finished executable. I use Docker for these builds.

I'm trying to decide what the cleanest approach is for managing these dependencies.

- git submodules and build binaries from source each time (longest build)
- build libraries individually and store them as artifacts/releases for each repo (most work, across several repos)
- make a README on how to rebuild and commit the binaries to the main  repo (feels dirty for some reason)

What is the common practice in c++ for dealing with these intermediate binaries?

Comment: Definitely not the third! A good DevOps CI process automates steps like that one. The second one is a good ideal to aim for as it keeps the projects maximally independent. However it's a lot of work to set up. If that were the end goal you should find an incremental path to get there and not rely on all that scaffolding being setup before your project is useable...

Comment: ...The first is a great starting point, and maybe even finishing point. You should be able to avoid long rebuilds by leaning into Docker's layer caching. It should work out of the box on your workstations, and you can even keep your CI process speedy if you enable it there. I might stay away from submodules though. They're kind of janky. Have you looked into subtrees? Subtrees are a nice alternative to submodules.

Comment: You've cross-tagged this with [tag:git], so I'd mention here that it's usually unwise to store *any* binaries in Git, and almost always unwise to store any *build products* / artifacts in Git: Git is meant for storing human-manipulated sources.

Comment: With ccache the option 1 rebuilds should run *really* fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably impossible to give a generally valid answer. You have to think about who the users of your code (I mean those who compile it) are and what their workflow is.

I personally more and more tend to favor option three in your list - yes, the README file. The reason is that in many cases the users don't need to (and should not) bother with dependencies at all. Very often there is the higher-level build process in place, that makes sure all dependencies are properly prepared (downloaded, optionally patched, compiled and installed) as your application expects. With Docker, I have the feeling this is becoming the norm now. I always provide a Dockerfile (or sometimes even a complete Docker image) where all dependencies are in place and the user can compile without even thinking of those.

If it's not Docker, there may be an other higher-level build process that handles dependencies. As I'm in the embedded industry, we use mostly Yocto, but there are others also. The users don't even need to use Yocto themselves, as I provide them with an SDK that contains all dependencies.

And for the very few who refuse to use all these options and insist on compiling natively on their main machine, I write a list of dependencies in the README file, with a few lines on each, describing how to fetch, compile and install them.

As for the other two options you mentioned:

- Option one (git submodules) - I must say that I never really got comfortable with that. IMO they are a bit poorly implemented in git (e.g. it's really cumbersome to find out exactly at which version each submodule is currently checked out). Also, with a higher-level build process in place, it might mean double-fetching each dependency, which is inefficient. Then it's hard to apply patches to the dependency, if you must. You would have to write some extra script and include it in your build process. Lastly, your dependencies may have dependencies by themselves, and then it gets really ugly.
- Option two (storing binary artifacts in the repo) is an absolute emergency solution that I would always try to avoid.

And because somebody mentioned git subtrees - we tried that in our team for about half a year. It was an absolute disaster. Nobody really understood it, and about once a week someone messed up the entire repository. Never would I use that again.

Comment: "it's really cumbersome to find out exactly at which version each submodule is currently checked out" . . . huh? `git -C submodule describe` is hard?

Comment: Well, what if you didn't clone the repo in the first place, but just look at it on some web interface (github, bitbucket, etc.)? Or if you want to know for a specific commit in the past, what versions of the submodules were used back then? What I would expect from a multi-repo tool is that there simply is a file that lists all dependencies in their respective version. And that file should be versioned itself like normal code, so I can easily see and compare it. The git-repo tool for example does a much better job in that (though it has many other nuisances).